# JavaScript/JQuery how set time before method can be called again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, queue, keypress

I am working on a game. My event handlers are using JQuery, and the game is written in JavaScript, and I've been trying to find the best way to set time before a method can be called again from my event listeners.

Here is my current event listener:

```
function shootingHandler(key){
    switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)){
        case UpArrow:
        case Spacebar:
            setTimeout(player.shoot(), 1000);
            break;
    }
}
```

The `setTimeout()` method doesn't work for this, because it just calls the method, then waits for specified time, then fires it. So in my example code, I'm trying to make it so the `player` can only fire a shot every second, but if the player holds down spacebar it auto shoots thousands of times.

What is a good way to make a method only able to be called once at a time, only only once every few seconds or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var disabled = false;
var shootOnEnabled = false;
function shootingHandler(key){
    switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)){
        case UpArrow:
        case Spacebar:
            if (disabled) { 
                shootOnEnabled = true;
                break; 
            }
            shoot();
            disabled = true;
            setTimeout(function () {
                disabled = false;
                if (shootOnEnabled) {
                    shootOnEnabled = false;
                    shootingHandler(key);  
                }
            }, 1000);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that works really well! Do you know if there is a way for me to make it so that if they press `Spacebar` or `UpArrow` before it is re-enabled, that it will shoot it automatically once enabled?

Comment: I've edited my answer so that I think it will achieve what you are asking for.

Comment: And nice use of recursion :D

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/pQFs4/)

```
var timerActive;
function shootingHandler(key){
  switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)){
    case UpArrow:
    case Spacebar:
            if (timerActive){
                clearTimeout(timerActive);
             }
            timerActive= setTimeout(player.shoot(), 1000);
            };
        break;
    }
}
```

here, if the function `shootingHandler` is called again before 1 second of previous call, the timer will be reset back to 0. so only if the player releases the space bar for 1 second the function will be triggered.
This is an old trick used to prevent window resize from triggering hundreds of times while dragging.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing, and it doesn't seem to actually work. At all.

Comment: here, if the function is called again before 1 second, the timer will be reset. so only if the player releases the space bar for 1 second the function will be triggered. its an old trick used to prevent window resize from triggering hundreds of time while dragging..

Comment: No because you are calling the `resizeTime = blabla` every time `Spacebar` or `UpArrow` is pressed.

Comment: can't you see `if (resizeTimer){
                clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
             }` above the `setTimeOut`? if the timer is already set and active, it'll reset the timer. the function `player.shoot()` will be triggered only if there is a gap of specified interval. otherwise it'll keep resetting the timer back to 0

Comment: That might be what you meant to put, but you have an extra end block "**}**", or you're missing an `else`

Comment: `resize` timer is just a variable name refering to the function lol.

Comment: @tanishalfelven for the sake of your understanding i changed the variable name.

Comment: The problem is, it resets the timer every time the button is pressed.

Comment: @tanishalfelven only if the previous timeout is still active.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Which is not what I want to do. Thanks for helping out, I picked another as answer but you helped a ton!

Answer (score 0):

if you are allowed to use other third party libraries check out Underscore

http://underscorejs.org/

It has a pretty nice function that does exactly what you need.

```
var throttled = _.throttle(updatePosition, 100);
$(window).scroll(throttled);
```

In this example *updatePosition* will be called not before every 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Seems like a good idea... How would I call a method that I already called `_.throttle()` on?

Comment: the main idea is to wrap an event handler with this... well, wrapper. Instead calling your method, create a new method... something like: this.wrappedMethod = _.throttle(this.Method);              then call the wrapperMethod where you were calling the original one

Answer (score 0):

In `player.shoot()`, check first to see if the player is allowed to shoot. Something like `if(allowedToShoot) { ... }`.

And in `shootingHandler`, call a function that sets the flag to `true`, calls the `player.shoot()`, and then sets the flag back to `false`. Something like `setTimeout(allowShooting(), 1000);`.

```
function allowShooting(){
    allowedToShoot = true;
    player.shoot();
    allowedToShoot = false;
}
```